# Nasty error when initializing vector

Tags: c++, vector

I am just trying to make a vector, but it gives me a huge error and I am following a working example from my other project. The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct organism {
    bool One;
    bool Two;
};
std::vector<organism> organisms;

int main() {
    printf("Content-type: text/html\n\n");
    printf("TEST");
    printf(getenv("QUERY_STRING"));

    return 0;
}
```

The error:

```
> "make" 
C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -o build/e2.exe source/main.cpp
C:\Users\Stephen\AppData\Local\Temp\ccc0a0w2.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorI8organismE10deallocateEPS1_j[__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<organism>::deallocate(organism*, unsigned int)]+0xd): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
C:\Users\Stephen\AppData\Local\Temp\ccc0a0w2.o:main.cpp:(.eh_frame$_ZNSt12_Vector_baseI8organismSaIS0_EED2Ev+0x13): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
C:\Users\Stephen\AppData\Local\Temp\ccc0a0w2.o:main.cpp:(.eh_frame$_ZNSt6vectorI8organismSaIS0_EED1Ev+0x13): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
"make": *** [build] Error 1

> Process Exit Code: 2
> Time Taken: 00:01
```

I can compile it if I comment out `std::vector<organism> organisms;` but I have no clue what's wrong with that line. It's exactly the same in my other project, which compiles fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to compile with `g++.exe` instead of `gcc.exe` so that it will know it needs to link with the C++ library.

Comment: Damnit. I just fixed another problem by compiling with gcc instead of g++; that is, g++ doesn't work with CGI/Apache.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask about that problem as a separate question. :)

Comment: You can also compile with `gcc` but pass `-lstdc++` as an option (to get the C++ library correctly linked in):  `gcc -o build/e2.exe source/main.cpp -lstdc++`.

Comment: @robmayoff I wasn't asking about it, just stating why it isn't a viable solution.